Create-T3-Turbo: next-auth v5 with KyselyAdapter type issues and server side errors
I've been working on refactoring my create-t3-turbo app to use a Prisma-Kysely combination instead of Drizzle. I am encountering type errors when using the KyselyAdapter from @auth/kysely-adapter in my authentication configuration, as well as issues with the crypto module on the edge runtime. Here are the details:
Code in db.ts:
import type { GeneratedAlways } from "kysely";
import { Kysely, PostgresDialect } from "kysely";
import { Pool } from "pg";

export interface Database {
  User: {
    id: GeneratedAlways<string>;
    name: string | null;
    email: string;
    emailVerified: Date | null;
    image: string | null;
  };
  Account: {
    id: GeneratedAlways<string>;
    userId: string;
    type: string;
    provider: string;
    providerAccountId: string;
    refresh_token: string | null;
    access_token: string | null;
    expires_at: number | null;
    token_type: string | null;
    scope: string | null;
    id_token: string | null;
    session_state: string | null;
  };
  Session: {
    id: GeneratedAlways<string>;
    userId: string;
    sessionToken: string;
    expires: Date;
  };
  VerificationToken: {
    identifier: string;
    token: string;
    expires: Date;
  };
}

export const db = new Kysely<Database>({
  dialect: new PostgresDialect({
    pool: new Pool({
      connectionString: process.env.POSTGRES_URL,
    }),
  }),
});

Code in config.ts:
import type { DefaultSession, NextAuthConfig, Session as NextAuthSession } from "next-auth";
import { KyselyAdapter } from "@auth/kysely-adapter";
import Discord from "next-auth/providers/discord";
import { env } from "../env";
import { db } from "./db";

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface Session {
    user: {
      id: string;
    } & DefaultSession["user"];
  }
}

const adapter = KyselyAdapter(db);

export const authConfig = {
  secret: env.AUTH_SECRET,
  providers: [Discord],
  callbacks: {
    session: (opts) => {
      if (!("user" in opts))
        throw new Error("unreachable with session strategy");
      return {
        ...opts.session,
        user: {
          ...opts.session.user,
          id: opts.user.id,
        },
      };
    },
  },
} satisfies NextAuthConfig;

export const validateToken = async (token: string): Promise<NextAuthSession | null> => {
  const sessionToken = token.slice("Bearer ".length);
  const session = await adapter.getSessionAndUser?.(sessionToken);
  return session ? {
      user: {
        ...session.user,
      },
      expires: session.session.expires.toISOString(),
    }
    : null;
};

I get the following type error on KyselyAdapter(db):
Argument of type 'KyselyAuth<Database, Database>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Kysely<Database>'.
  The types of 'fn.agg' are incompatible between these types.
    Type '<O>(name: string, args?: readonly import("D:/Repositories/Repositories/create-t3-turbo/node_modules/kysely/dist/esm/parser/reference-parser").ReferenceExpression<Database, keyof Database>[] | undefined) => import("D:/Repositories/Repositories/create-t3-turbo/node_modules/kysely/dist/esm/query-builder/aggregate-funct...' is not assignable to type '<O>(name: string, args?: readonly import("D:/Repositories/Repositories/create-t3-turbo/node_modules/kysely/dist/esm/parser/reference-parser").ReferenceExpression<import("D:/Repositories/Repositories/create-t3-turbo/node_modules/@auth/kysely-adapter/index").Database, keyof import("D:/Repositories/Repositories/create-...'.
      Types of parameters 'args' and 'args' are incompatible.
        Type 'readonly import("D:/Repositories/Repositories/create-t3-turbo/node_modules/kysely/dist/esm/parser/reference-parser").ReferenceExpression<import("D:/Repositories/Repositories/create-t3-turbo/node_modules/@auth/kysely-adapter/index").Database, keyof import("D:/Repositories/Repositories/create-t3-turbo/node_modules/@au...' is not assignable to type 'readonly import("D:/Repositories/Repositories/create-t3-turbo/node_modules/kysely/dist/esm/parser/reference-parser").ReferenceExpression<Database, keyof Database>[] | undefined'.
          Type 'readonly import("D:/Repositories/Repositories/create-t3-turbo/node_modules/kysely/dist/esm/parser/reference-parser").ReferenceExpression<import("D:/Repositories/Repositories/create-t3-turbo/node_modules/@auth/kysely-adapter/index").Database, keyof import("D:/Repositories/Repositories/create-t3-turbo/node_modules/@au...' is not assignable to type 'readonly import("D:/Repositories/Repositories/create-t3-turbo/node_modules/kysely/dist/esm/parser/reference-parser").ReferenceExpression<Database, keyof Database>[]'.
            Type 'import("D:/Repositories/Repositories/create-t3-turbo/node_modules/kysely/dist/esm/parser/reference-parser").ReferenceExpression<import("D:/Repositories/Repositories/create-t3-turbo/node_modules/@auth/kysely-adapter/index").Database, keyof import("D:/Repositories/Repositories/create-t3-turbo/node_modules/@auth/kysely...' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/Repositories/Repositories/create-t3-turbo/node_modules/kysely/dist/esm/parser/reference-parser").ReferenceExpression<Database, keyof Database>'.
              Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ReferenceExpression<Database, keyof Database>'.ts(2345)

I also attempted to use KyselyAuth, as recommended in the documentation (https://authjs.dev/getting-started/adapters/kysely), for added type-safety. However, this led to more type errors with my Database type:
export const db = new KyselyAuth<Database>({
  dialect: new PostgresDialect({
    pool: new Pool({
      host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
      database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
      user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
      password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    }),
  }),
});

When using KyselyAuth, I encounter this error:
Type 'Database' does not satisfy the constraint 'Database'.
The types of 'User.id' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'GeneratedAlways<string>' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Additionally, I am encountering an issue with the crypto module on the edge runtime:
Error: The edge runtime does not support Node.js 'crypto' module.
Learn More: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/node-module-in-edge-runtime

Strangely, I do not use crypto, I also commented export const runtime = "edge"; everywhere out.
Has anyone else faced these issues when using KyselyAdapter with next-auth and Kysely? How can I resolve these type errors and the edge runtime issue? Any advice would be greatly appreciated!
